# Improving my implementation of the sieve of Eratosthenes

Tags: python, performance, primes

I am creating a sieve of Eratosthenes in order to sum more efficiently the prime numbers between 1 and a large number n. What I want to do is to create a list from 2 to n, and then remove the multiples of 2, then the multiples of 3, then the multiples of the next number in the list, and so on. The code I have created I think it has very slow performance in time,  it is almost like creating a list by checking if each entry is a prime number. I guess the number of operations that I have is of order:
square root of n (the first while loop) times (a bit less than) square root of n (for the second while loop). So I am not sure if the remove method or maybe other thing is slowing it down.

My code is this one:

```
def sieve_of_Eratosthenes(n):
L= list(range(2,n+1))
# creates a list from 2 to n

i=2
while i*i <=n: # going to remove multiples of i, starting at i^2
    k=i        # if j <i then ij already checked
    while i*k <= max(L):
        try:
            L.remove(i*k)   # there is an error if the element is not in 
                            # the list so need to add these two lines
        except ValueError:  
            pass     # do nothing!
        k=k+1
    i=L[i-1]      # list index starts at 0, want i to be next element in the list
# print(L)
return L
```

Comment: There are many implementations posted [here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes#Python)

Comment: removing is the culprit, it destroys direct indexability. must not remove, but instead mark without removing. removing removes by value so must scan through the list so each removal is O(n); O(1) marking by index is the goal, and the precondition for overall speed.

Comment: @WillNess that is the answer I was looking for! thanks

Comment: to contradict myself, some removals are not O(n), so those removals are good. some are O(1) (hash tables) some are O(log n) (from trees, or when merging sorted increasing lists of multiples) which is tolerable.

Comment: here says deleting an element from a list is O(n) https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: yes. it depends on implementation. if your list is implemented as a hash table, it's O(1) (with potentially big constant factor). if it is implemented as a tree, it's O(log n).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Assumption**

> The question is on how to improve the run time of your software since it's very slow.`

Performed following two code changes to speed up your code

1. Rather than keeping a list of primes, check numbers as Prime (True)
   or non-Prime (False)
2. Check only odd numbers > 2 for prime

**Code**

```
def sieve_of_Eratosthenes2(n):
    if n < 2:
        return []
    if n < 3:
        return [2]

    L = [True] * (n+1)    # all numbers set as primes initially

    # modifies prime flag in list for odd numbers
    for i in range(3, n, 2): # Check odd numbers for prime (no need to check even numbers)
        if L[i]: # A prime
            L[i*i::i] = [False]*len(L[i*i::i]) # from i^2 in increments of i

    # Report prime 2 + odd primes
    return [2] + [i for i in range(3, n, 2) if L[i]]  # Get odd numbers whose flag is 
                                                      # still True
```

*New Code*

```
%timeit sieve_of_Eratosthenes2(1000)
188 µs ± 16.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
%timeit sieve_of_Eratosthenes2(100000)
16 ms ± 1.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

In going from 1, 000 to 100, 000 time 
(i.e. 100X), time increased by ~85, 
so almost linear
```

*Old Code*

```
 %timeit sieve_of_Eratosthenes(1000)
 25.2 ms ± 1.59 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
 sieve_of_Eratosthenes2(100000)
 261.45 seconds  (using time module)

In going from 1, 000 to 100, 000 (100X)
time increased by factor of ~10, 000
So quadratic increase in time (i.e. 100^2).
```

**Explanation**

The complexity of [Sieve of Eratosthenes](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sieve-eratosthenes-0n-time-complexity/) is

```
O(N log (log N))
```

Which is nearly linear, since operations are normally O(1) to mark numbers in an array as True (prime) and False (non-prime).

In the original algorithm numbers non-prime numbers where removed rather than marked which takes:

```
O(N) per removal.
```

This adds an additional factor of N to the complexity of Sieve of Eratosthenes causing the original algorithm complexity to be:

```
O(N*N*log (log N))
```

Thus nearly quadratic as confirmed by the run times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, just a couple of small questions:
in the original definition of your list,
L = [True] * (n+1)
I am guessing that you want a list of n Trues, where it does not matter how long it is, as long as it is longer than n+1 (because lists indexes start at 0). This is because, in the end, you just care about those positions (up to n) storing a True (these are going to be the list of prime numbers).
The second question: shouldn’t it be 
range(3, n+1, 2)
(so that it includes n, in case n is odd)?

Comment: @inquisitor--answer is yes to all  your questions.  As an aside you will note that we only use odd indices in the array (since we know evens are non-prime).  This allows you to reduce the array size in half but requires slightly more complex indexing into the array.

Comment: one size-point comparisons are mostly meaningless. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth, please!

Comment: @WillNess--added additional explanation and data point.  Does this add more meaning?

Comment: yes, for sure. cheers!   (btw there was no notification, because there was no space before the "--" )